# Insert Data Between Two Dates in Database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I need help. We need to insert data between two dates in the database using C# on button click

For example, we have two calendars, `Calendar1` & `Calendar2`.

- Now from `Calendar1`, we choose date 01/12/2018
- And from `Calendar2`, we choose date 30/12/2018

When we click the "Submit" button, we need to insert the data into the database

01/12/2018 to 30/12/2018

Ex.

```
01/12/2018
02/12/2018
03/12/2018
```

Comment: Welcome! What did you try to solve your problem? Please edit your question and insert the code you have.

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear. Is this a problem inserting data in the database or something else. Probably adding the code that you have written so far trying to solve the problem will be helpful

Comment: Respected Sir, Now i edited My Question Please check

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a table between two dates using recursive CTEs:

```
with dates as (
      select @startdate as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < @enddate
     )
select *
from dates
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

That said, if you need to do this for a user interface, then I think you really need a calendar table, with one row per date.  Then you can simply do:

```
select c.dte
from calendar c
where c.dte >= @startdate and c.dte <= @enddate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer a Tally Table to an rCTE for things like this; for larger data sets a Tally Table tends to be much faster:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20181201',
        @EndDate date = '20181231';

WITH N AS (
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --10000 rows
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate)
FROM Tally T
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) <= @EndDate;
```